# How to override the create method in Odoo 16?

Tags: odoo, odoo-16

I am trying to override a create method in `stock.move` table.

```
    @api.model_create_multi
      def create(self, vals_list):
          print('cccccccccc ',vals_list) # Here I am getting a empty list.
          for vals in vals_list:
              if vals.get('quantity_done') and 'lot_ids' in vals:
                  vals.pop('lot_ids')
          res = super().create(vals_list)
          return res
```

But I am getting empty in `vals_list` when I print it. Why it is empty? am I missing something?

Comment: Probably a mistake before calling the create. Your override looks correct.

Comment: The fact that your `print`  function gets executed, that means your `create` method has successfully overridden. If you want to know why you are getting empty `vals_list`, you need to trace back to where it is creating this object to find out.